# Unity read XML directly instead of incorporating them in assetbundles

Tags: xml, dictionary, unity-game-engine, assets

I have some code that reads text from XML file, those files have been added to assetbundles, from what I have seen it seems there is a bundle per file.

I want to avoid using bundles and read the XML contents directly. Right now the code using the bundles is this:

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string,int> kvp in xmlFileDic)
{
string name = kvp.Key;
string path = xmlBasePath + name + ".assetbundle";
int version = kvp.Value;
WWW www = WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload(path,kvp.Value);
yield return www;           
AssetBundleRequest ab = www.assetBundle.LoadAsync(name,typeof(TextAsset));
yield return ab;                    
xmlLoadDic.Add(name,(TextAsset)ab.asset);
www.assetBundle.Unload(false);

...
and reading data
...

string gamerules = FileManagement.xmlLoadDic["GameMasterData"].text;
//string gamerules = www.text;
//Debug.Log("master path:"+masterPath+"game rules:"+gamerules);
System.IO.TextReader reader = new System.IO.StringReader(gamerules);
SmallXmlParser parser = new SmallXmlParser();
MasterDataHandler handler = new MasterDataHandler();
parser.Parse(reader,handler);

mPhaseList = handler.phaseList;
```

Any hints on how I could do this easily?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. This loads a XML file from the Resources folder and loads into a XElement that you can use LinQ to read and do stuff with it. Here is some sample code to help you get started :

```
        public class XMLReader : MonoBehaviour 
        { 
            XElement someXML;
            void Awake()
            {
              TextAsset textAsset = (TextAsset)Resources.Load("Name_OF_XML_File");
              TextReader txtReader = new StringReader(textAsset.text);
              someXML= XElement.Load(txtReader);
              string someData = (from data in someXML.Descendants("node") select data.Element("Element_Name").Value).ToString();
            }
        }
```